Enumeration counter in paracol resumes unexpectetly in second column
I have a document with a significant portion in parallel columns using the package paracol.
But with the numbering of the enumerates I have an issue.
My expectation is that the right column does NOT resume the numbering. Left column is numbered as expected and restarting at 1 (respective (a) for each enumerate).
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{easyReview}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \end{enumerate}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

Another text

\begin{paracol}{2} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item Left Col No 1 \switchcolumn 
\item \highlight{Right Col No 1} \switchcolumn* 

\begin{enumerate}
\item Left Nested Col No (a) \switchcolumn 
\item Right Nested Col No (a) \switchcolumn* 
\item Left Nested Col No (b) \switchcolumn 
\item Right Nested Col No (b) \switchcolumn* 

\end{enumerate}

 
\item Left Col No 2\switchcolumn 
\item \highlight{Right Col No 2} \switchcolumn* 

 \begin{enumerate} 
\item Left Nested Col No (a) \switchcolumn 
\item \highlight{Right Nested Col No (a)} \switchcolumn* 
\item Left Nested Col No (b) \switchcolumn 
\item \highlight{Right Nested Col No (b)} \switchcolumn* 

\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\end{document} 


The highlighted items are not numbered as I expect.
Does somebody can help? Best regards

The only way to get enumerate to affect both columns equally is to put it outside the paracol environment.  So you can either stay inside paracol and keep starting and stopping enumerate every time you switch columns, or you can keep stopping and starting paracol inside nested enumerates.
Alas, \switchcolumn*[\begin{enumerate}] doesn't work.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{easyReview}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \end{enumerate}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{0}

Another text

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{paracol}{2} 
\item Left Col No 1 \switchcolumn
\item \highlight{Right Col No 1} \switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\begin{enumerate}% nested
\begin{paracol}{2}
\item Left Nested Col No (a) \switchcolumn 
\item Right Nested Col No (a) \switchcolumn* 
\item Left Nested Col No (b) \switchcolumn 
\item Right Nested Col No (b) \switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\item Left Col No 2\switchcolumn 
\item \highlight{Right Col No 2} \switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\begin{enumerate}% nested
\begin{paracol}{2}
\item Left Nested Col No (a) \switchcolumn 
\item \highlight{Right Nested Col No (a)} \switchcolumn* 
\item Left Nested Col No (b) \switchcolumn 
\item \highlight{Right Nested Col No (b)} \switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document} 


Thanks. Another solution is to use synccounter after begin{enumerate}, which is within paracol: \begin{enumerate} \synccounter{enumii}
However, both variants are not very handy. Is there a chance to redefine the command \begin{enumerate}?

It would have to be a local change inside paracol.  See also \AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{...}.  Note that \begin{enumerate} also adds spacing (to one column only).
