Paracol: synchronise columns within a proof or similar environment?
I’m setting a mathematical translation using paracol, with the original and translation in parallel columns.  In general, I’m synchronising columns after every paragraph — [column 1 paragraph text] \switchcolumn [column 2 paragraph text] \switchcolumn*, and so on.
How can I maintain this synchronisation scheme, when a proof-type environment contains multiple paragraphs?  If I issue \switchcolumn(*) after every paragraph as usual, then the proof environment delimiters get mismatched: we get first the \begin{proof} of column 1, then the \begin{proof} of col 2, then \end{proof} of column 1, then (after switching) the \end{proof} of col 2.  If both are a plain proof environment, then this actually comes out as desired — but if they’re not exactly the same environment, then this fails, and it’s clearly “wrong” even in the case when it works.  On the other hand, if I don’t switch/synchronise until after the proof environments are closed, then of course the paragraphs within the proofs don’t get synced as desired.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol,lipsum,amssymb,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{boldproof}{\begin{proof}[\textbf{Proof.}]\renewcommand*{\qedsymbol}{\(\blacksquare\)}}{\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \lipsum[1][1-2] \switchcolumn
  \lipsum[2][1-2] \switchcolumn*
  \lipsum[3][1-2] \switchcolumn
  \lipsum[4][1-2] \switchcolumn*
  \begin{theorem}
    There exists some $x \in \mathbb{N}$.
  \end{theorem}
  \switchcolumn
  \begin{theorem}
    There exists some $x \in \mathbb{N}$.
  \end{theorem}
  \switchcolumn*

% (1) environment ends/beginnings placed as though columns were truly independent; paras synchronised, but environments are in fact interleaved, so only works when both are the same environment (and only for certain simple environments)
  \begin{proof}
   Take for instance $x = 1$.
  \switchcolumn
  \begin{proof}
    Take for instance $x = 0$.  Some people adopt the convention that $\mathbb{N}$ excludes $0$, but here I prefer to include it.
   \switchcolumn*
    This clearly witnesses the desired conclusion.
  \end{proof}
  \switchcolumn
    This then clearly witnesses the desired conclusion.
  \end{proof}
  \switchcolumn*

% (2) environments appropriately nested in source; but output paragraphs not synchronised.
  \begin{proof}
    Take for instance $x = 1$.

    This clearly witnesses the desired conclusion.
  \end{proof}
  \switchcolumn
  \begin{boldproof}
    Take for instance $x = 0$.  Some people adopt the convention that $\mathbb{N}$ excludes $0$, but here I prefer to include it.

    This then clearly witnesses the desired conclusion.
  \end{boldproof}
  \switchcolumn*
  
\end{paracol}
\end{document}


You can stop paracol, start proof, then restart paracol.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730752/enumeration-counter-in-paracol-resumes-unexpectetly-in-second-column/730769?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#730769
