How to create a long parcolums with two columns where the counters on both sides are aligned with each other?
I am trying to make a long columns contaning two columns. One side is France and one side is English. My code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paracol} 

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn* 
\section*{English}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, start=1, nosep,leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=*,itemindent=\parindent,align=left]
    \item “REJOICE AND BE GLAD” (Mt 5:12), Jesus tells those persecuted or humiliated for his sake. The Lord asks everything of us, and in return he offers us true life, the happiness for which we were created. He wants us to be saints and not to settle for a bland and mediocre existence. The call to holiness is present in various ways from the very first pages of the Bible. We see it expressed in the Lord’s words to Abraham: “Walk before me, and be blameless” (Gen 17:1).
        \item What follows is not meant to be a treatise on holiness, containing definitions and distinctions helpful for understanding this important subject, or a discussion of the various means of sanctification. My modest goal is to repropose the call to holiness in a practical way for our own time, with all its risks, challenges and opportunities. For the Lord has chosen each one of us “to be holy and blameless before him in love” (Eph 1:4).
\end{enumerate}

\switchcolumn
\section*{Français}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, start=1, nosep,leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=*,itemindent=\parindent,align=left]
    \item « Soyez dans la joie et l’allégresse » (Mt 5, 12), dit Jésus à ceux qui sont persécutés ou humiliés à cause de lui. Le Seigneur demande tout ; et ce qu’il offre est la vraie vie, le bonheur pour lequel nous avons été créés. Il veut que nous soyons saints et il n’attend pas de nous que nous nous contentions d’une existence médiocre, édulcorée, sans consistance. En réalité, dès les premières pages de la Bible, il y a, sous diverses formes, l’appel à la sainteté. Voici comment le Seigneur le proposait à Abraham : « Marche en ma présence et sois parfait » (Gn 17, 1).
\item  Il ne faut pas s’attendre, ici, à un traité sur la sainteté, avec de nombreuses définitions et distinctions qui pourraient enrichir cet important thème, ou avec des analyses qu’on pourrait faire concernant les moyens de sanctification. Mon humble objectif, c’est de faire résonner une fois de plus l’appel à la sainteté, en essayant de l’insérer dans le contexte actuel, avec ses risques, ses défis et ses opportunités. En effet, le Seigneur a élu chacun d’entre nous pour que nous soyons « saints et immaculés en sa présence, dans l’amour » (Ep 1, 4).
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}


How can I make the counters on both sides are aligned with each other?

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730752/enumeration-counter-in-paracol-resumes-unexpectetly-in-second-column

Since you're using the enumitem package, you can split your environments by setting the series key in the first environments and refer to it with the resume key in later.  Code:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{%
  label=\textbf{\arabic*.},
  nosep,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  labelwidth=*,
  itemindent=
  \parindent,
  align=left
}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

  \section*{Français}
  \selectlanguage{french}
  \begin{enumerate}[series=f_enum]
  \item « Soyez dans la joie et l’allégresse » (Mt 5, 12), dit Jésus à
    ceux qui sont persécutés ou humiliés à cause de lui. Le Seigneur
    demande tout ; et ce qu’il offre est la vraie vie, le bonheur pour
    lequel nous avons été créés. Il veut que nous soyons saints et il
    n’attend pas de nous que nous nous contentions d’une existence
    médiocre, édulcorée, sans consistance. En réalité, dès les
    premières pages de la Bible, il y a, sous diverses formes, l’appel
    à la sainteté. Voici comment le Seigneur le proposait à Abraham :
    « Marche en ma présence et sois parfait » (Gn 17, 1).
  \end{enumerate}

  \switchcolumn

  \section*{English}
  \selectlanguage{english}
  \begin{enumerate}[series=e_enum]
  \item “REJOICE AND BE GLAD” (Mt 5:12), Jesus tells those persecuted
    or humiliated for his sake. The Lord asks everything of us, and in
    return he offers us true life, the happiness for which we were
    created. He wants us to be saints and not to settle for a bland
    and mediocre existence. The call to holiness is present in various
    ways from the very first pages of the Bible. We see it expressed
    in the Lord’s words to Abraham: “Walk before me, and be blameless”
    (Gen 17:1).
  \end{enumerate}

  \switchcolumn*

  \selectlanguage{french}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume=f_enum]    
  \item Il ne faut pas s’attendre, ici, à un traité sur la sainteté,
    avec de nombreuses définitions et distinctions qui pourraient
    enrichir cet important thème, ou avec des analyses qu’on pourrait
    faire concernant les moyens de sanctification. Mon humble
    objectif, c’est de faire résonner une fois de plus l’appel à la
    sainteté, en essayant de l’insérer dans le contexte actuel, avec
    ses risques, ses défis et ses opportunités. En effet, le Seigneur
    a élu chacun d’entre nous pour que nous soyons « saints et
    immaculés en sa présence, dans l’amour » (Ep 1, 4).
  \end{enumerate}

  \switchcolumn
  \selectlanguage{english}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume=e_enum]
  \item What follows is not meant to be a treatise on holiness,
    containing definitions and distinctions helpful for understanding
    this important subject, or a discussion of the various means of
    sanctification. My modest goal is to repropose the call to
    holiness in a practical way for our own time, with all its risks,
    challenges and opportunities. For the Lord has chosen each one of
    us “to be holy and blameless before him in love” (Eph 1:4).
  \end{enumerate}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}

which looks like this:

I think this should work for small portions of text, but it's probably too painful if you want to typeset longer ones.

You can try this
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paracol} 
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, nosep, leftmargin=0pt, labelwidth=*, itemindent=\parindent, align=left]
    \item “REJOICE AND BE GLAD” (Mt 5:12), Jesus tells those persecuted or humiliated for his sake. The Lord asks everything of us, and in return he offers us true life, the happiness for which we were created. He wants us to be saints and not to settle for a bland and mediocre existence. The call to holiness is present in various ways from the very first pages of the Bible. We see it expressed in the Lord’s words to Abraham: “Walk before me, and be blameless” (Gen17:1).
    \switchcolumn
    \item  « Soyez dans la joie et l’allégresse » (Mt 5, 12), dit Jésus à
    ceux qui sont persécutés ou humiliés à cause de lui. Le Seigneur
    demande tout ; et ce qu’il offre est la vraie vie, le bonheur pour
    lequel nous avons été créés. Il veut que nous soyons saints et il
    n’attend pas de nous que nous nous contentions d’une existence
    médiocre, édulcorée, sans consistance. En réalité, dès les
    premières pages de la Bible, il y a, sous diverses formes, l’appel
    à la sainteté. Voici comment le Seigneur le proposait à Abraham :
    « Marche en ma présence et sois parfait » (Gn 17, 1).
    \switchcolumn*
    \item What follows is not meant to be a treatise on holiness, containing definitions and distinctions helpful for understanding this important subject, or a discussion of the various means of sanctification. My modest goal is to repropose the call to holiness in a practical way for our own time, with all its risks, challenges and opportunities. For the Lord has chosen each one of us “to be holy and blameless before him in love” (\textit{Eph}~$1:4)$.
    \switchcolumn
    \item  Il ne faut pas s’attendre, ici, à un traité sur la sainteté,
    avec de nombreuses définitions et distinctions qui pourraient
    enrichir cet important thème, ou avec des analyses qu’on pourrait
    faire concernant les moyens de sanctification. Mon humble
    objectif, c’est de faire résonner une fois de plus l’appel à la
    sainteté, en essayant de l’insérer dans le contexte actuel, avec
    ses risques, ses défis et ses opportunités. En effet, le Seigneur
    a élu chacun d’entre nous pour que nous soyons « saints et
    immaculés en sa présence, dans l’amour » (Ep 1, 4).\switchcolumn*
    
    \item “REJOICE AND BE GLAD” (Mt 5:12), Jesus tells those persecuted or humiliated for his sake. The Lord asks everything of us, and in return he offers us true life, the happiness for which we were created. He wants us to be saints and not to settle for a bland and mediocre existence. The call to holiness is present in various ways from the very first pages of the Bible. We see it expressed in the Lord’s words to Abraham: “Walk before me, and be blameless” (Gen17:1).
    \switchcolumn
    \item  « Soyez dans la joie et l’allégresse » (Mt 5, 12), dit Jésus à
    ceux qui sont persécutés ou humiliés à cause de lui. Le Seigneur
    demande tout ; et ce qu’il offre est la vraie vie, le bonheur pour
    lequel nous avons été créés. Il veut que nous soyons saints et il
    n’attend pas de nous que nous nous contentions d’une existence
    médiocre, édulcorée, sans consistance. En réalité, dès les
    premières pages de la Bible, il y a, sous diverses formes, l’appel
    à la sainteté. Voici comment le Seigneur le proposait à Abraham :
    « Marche en ma présence et sois parfait » (Gn 17, 1).
    \switchcolumn*
    \item What follows is not meant to be a treatise on holiness, containing definitions and distinctions helpful for understanding this important subject, or a discussion of the various means of sanctification. My modest goal is to repropose the call to holiness in a practical way for our own time, with all its risks, challenges and opportunities. For the Lord has chosen each one of us “to be holy and blameless before him in love” (\textit{Eph}~$1:4)$.
    \switchcolumn
    \item  Il ne faut pas s’attendre, ici, à un traité sur la sainteté,
    avec de nombreuses définitions et distinctions qui pourraient
    enrichir cet important thème, ou avec des analyses qu’on pourrait
    faire concernant les moyens de sanctification. Mon humble
    objectif, c’est de faire résonner une fois de plus l’appel à la
    sainteté, en essayant de l’insérer dans le contexte actuel, avec
    ses risques, ses défis et ses opportunités. En effet, le Seigneur
    a élu chacun d’entre nous pour que nous soyons « saints et
    immaculés en sa présence, dans l’amour » (Ep 1, 4).\switchcolumn*
    \item “REJOICE AND BE GLAD” (Mt 5:12), Jesus tells those persecuted or humiliated for his sake. The Lord asks everything of us, and in return he offers us true life, the happiness for which we were created. He wants us to be saints and not to settle for a bland and mediocre existence. The call to holiness is present in various ways from the very first pages of the Bible. We see it expressed in the Lord’s words to Abraham: “Walk before me, and be blameless” (Gen17:1).
    \switchcolumn
    \item  « Soyez dans la joie et l’allégresse » (Mt 5, 12), dit Jésus à
    ceux qui sont persécutés ou humiliés à cause de lui. Le Seigneur
    demande tout ; et ce qu’il offre est la vraie vie, le bonheur pour
    lequel nous avons été créés. Il veut que nous soyons saints et il
    n’attend pas de nous que nous nous contentions d’une existence
    médiocre, édulcorée, sans consistance. En réalité, dès les
    premières pages de la Bible, il y a, sous diverses formes, l’appel
    à la sainteté. Voici comment le Seigneur le proposait à Abraham :
    « Marche en ma présence et sois parfait » (Gn 17, 1).
    \switchcolumn*
    \item What follows is not meant to be a treatise on holiness, containing definitions and distinctions helpful for understanding this important subject, or a discussion of the various means of sanctification. My modest goal is to repropose the call to holiness in a practical way for our own time, with all its risks, challenges and opportunities. For the Lord has chosen each one of us “to be holy and blameless before him in love” (\textit{Eph}~$1:4)$.
    \switchcolumn
    \item  Il ne faut pas s’attendre, ici, à un traité sur la sainteté,
    avec de nombreuses définitions et distinctions qui pourraient
    enrichir cet important thème, ou avec des analyses qu’on pourrait
    faire concernant les moyens de sanctification. Mon humble
    objectif, c’est de faire résonner une fois de plus l’appel à la
    sainteté, en essayant de l’insérer dans le contexte actuel, avec
    ses risques, ses défis et ses opportunités. En effet, le Seigneur
    a élu chacun d’entre nous pour que nous soyons « saints et
    immaculés en sa présence, dans l’amour » (Ep 1, 4).\switchcolumn*
   \end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}


